# Access Control in MongoDB

Tags: security, mongodb, node.js

Lets say an application is written purely using JavaScript with node.js that connects directly to the MongoDB backend.

In this scenario is it possible to have a secure application where users login and have privilege separation like administrative/user/guest.  If so how does this work?  What would it require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchDB has a concept of users and authentication.

Take a look at the [`_users` database documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview)

I have some [code that talks to `_users`](https://github.com/Raynos/raynos-blog/blob/master/model/auth.js)

Comment: hmm transmitting the username/password in plain text for every request is not something i would call secure.   Although CouchDB does have a session handler...

Comment: @Rook of course you connect through HTTPS or use HTTP Basic auth. I also seem to have made the mistake of reading "mongoDB" as "couchDB"

Comment: No I gave you a +1 this is still interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js has some modules for various authentication methods, [connect-auth](https://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth/) looks like a good place to start.  You could then map your authenticated node.js credentials to a [MongoDB database user](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication) when connecting to the database.

Security in MongoDB is currently fairly basic, user permissions restrict access per database and can be either read/write or read-only, so you might use a database per user.